# Using submit() replaces space values with “+” and "," with "%252C" how to modify?

Tags: javascript, php

After using the code below all spaces changed to `+` and all `,` to `%252C`.

```
<select name="country" id="country" onchange="action='<?php 
echo '/index.php' ?>';submit();return false;">
```

I need to change spaces to `-` and keep `,` unchanged. and this is function to execute country values.

```
    function list_es($type, $country) {

    global $countries, $l, $lang;

    if($type=="dropdown") {

        // echo '<option value = "">- Select -</option>';
        foreach($countries as $country1) {

        echo '<option value="'. $country1.'"';

        echo $country1 == $l ? 'selected="selected"' : '';


        echo '>'.$country1.'</option>';
        echo "\n";
        }
```

Comment: This behavior is by design.  Learn about URL escaping.

Comment: You haven't shown the relevant code, which is the PHP code where you're *getting* the value. Normally you wouldn't see the URI-encoding, because normally it's decoded for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just standard URI-encoding. If you access it in the normal way, it's decoded for you:

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
```

If you then want to change spaces to dashes, just do a replace.

```
$country = str_replace($_GET['country'], ' ', '-');
```

---

(If your form is using POST rather than GET, just change `$_GET` above to `$_POST`.)